# WebView audio play pauses the default music player

Tags: android, android-webview

Is it normal, that android pauses the music track in the default music player if I play a track in my WebView app (It works with other players like PlayerPro)?

1. Play track in my music player (background)
2. Start webview app
3. Play track:

   audio = new Audio(path);
     audio.play();
4. After play(), the track in my music player is paused

I guess webview takes the same api as the default music player, but is there a workaround?

Comment: don't take audiofocus

Comment: I don't take that, or is that default? I don't think so I can handle that with the javascript audio api.

Comment: Hmm I still have the problem. I'm not sure if the audio focus is the reason for this. Does webview automatically request audio focus?

Comment: Apparently when webview starts to play music it gains audiofocus. That's why your player pauses.

Comment: And there is no workaround?

Comment: Such a big question and no answers! Looks like nobody bothered that webview handles audio focus independent from app.